# My html/javascript play button won't play embedded youtube videos

Tags: javascript, python, flask, youtube-data-api

I am trying to have a javascript play button, start the embedded video.
Everything is running locally 127.0.0.1:5000, if I click the red play button, the video plays.  But if I click on the play button from the html page, the embedded video produces the error below.

I've been stuck on this for a few days so I decided to come here and post all of my code, I would've used snippets, but I thought you may need to review them all.

Also, once I click on the html play button and it just shows a black video window with the red play button, then clicking on the red button will produce the error on the screenshot.

[image: Error when click on html play button, but will play if I click on red youtube button, prior to clicking on html play button]

[image: console log of video_url]

[image: image of play button]

app.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
from gtts import gTTS

app = Flask(__name__)

# Enter your API key here
API_KEY = 'redacted'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video_url = request.form['video_url']
        video_id = get_video_id(video_url)

        # Retrieve the video transcript
        try:
            transcript = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(video_id)
            subtitles = [{'text': entry['text'], 'start': entry['start']} for entry in transcript]

            # Generate audio files for each subtitle if they don't exist
            for subtitle in subtitles:
                audio_path = f'audio/{subtitle["start"]}.mp3'
                audio_full_path = os.path.join(app.static_folder, audio_path)

                if not os.path.isfile(audio_full_path):
                    tts = gTTS(text=subtitle['text'], lang='en', tld='com')  # Specify tld='com' for female voice
                    tts.save(audio_full_path)

                subtitle['audio_path'] = audio_path

        except:
            subtitles = []

        # Retrieve the video details using the YouTube Data API
        try:
            youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=API_KEY)
            video_info = youtube.videos().list(part='snippet', id=video_id).execute()
            video_title = video_info['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
            video_embed_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{video_id}"

            return render_template('result.html', video_title=video_title, video_embed_url=video_embed_url, subtitles=subtitles)
        except:
            return render_template('result.html', error_message='Failed to retrieve video details')

    return render_template('index.html')


def get_video_id(video_url):
    # Parse the video ID from the URL
    video_id = video_url.split('v=')[1]
    return video_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ video_title }}</h1>
    {% if error_message %}
        <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <div>
            <iframe id="video-player" width="560" height="315" src="{{ video_embed_url }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="play-button" onclick="playVideo()">Play Video</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            {% for subtitle in subtitles %}
                <p>{{ subtitle['text'] }}</p>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename=subtitle['audio_path']) }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <script>
        console.log("Video Embed URL:", "{{ video_embed_url }}");

        function playVideo() {
            var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');
            videoPlayer.src += "&autoplay=1";
            document.getElementById('play-button').style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dub.dat(youtube)</title>
    <script>
        function displayProgress() {
            var progressBar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
            progressBar.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>YouTube Subtitle Scraper</h1>
    <form action="/" method="POST" onsubmit="displayProgress()">
        <label for="video_url">YouTube Video URL:</label>
        <input type="text" name="video_url" id="video_url" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <progress id="progress-bar" style="display: none;"></progress>
</body>
</html>
```

video.js

```
function formatTime(time) {
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);

    var formattedTime = ("0" + hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + minutes).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
    return formattedTime;
}

function playSubtitle(subtitleData) {
    var currentTime = Math.floor(videoPlayer.currentTime);

    for (var i = 0; i < subtitleData.length; i++) {
        var subtitle = subtitleData[i];
        var startTime = Math.floor(subtitle.start);
        var endTime = Math.floor(subtitle.start + subtitle.duration);

        if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
            // Display the subtitle
            var subtitleElement = document.getElementById("translatedSubtitle");
            subtitleElement.textContent = subtitle.translatedText;

            // Check if translation is needed
            if (subtitle.text !== subtitle.translatedText) {
                // Run GTTS for the translated subtitle
                var tts = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(subtitle.translatedText);
                speechSynthesis.speak(tts);
            }
        }
    }
}

function syncSubtitle(audioPlayer) {
    var startTime = parseFloat(audioPlayer.id);
    videoPlayer.currentTime = startTime;
}

var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
var subtitles = {{ subtitles|tojson }};
var audioPlayers = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

videoPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    playSubtitle(subtitles);
});

for (var i = 0; i < audioPlayers.length; i++) {
    audioPlayers[i].addEventListener('play', function() {
        syncSubtitle(this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking for a while I found it.

Just replace the '&' for '?' in the playVideo() function.

videoPlayer.src += "&autoplay=1"; -> videoPlayer.src += "?autoplay=1";

Cheers!

Comment: Man, 3 days, thank you so much.  It makes sense & I wouldn't had thought to check that!  Atleast you've restored my faith in chatGPT not taking all of our jobs...

Comment: Hahahaha you're right, our jobs are safe for now